# GCP+Ansible: how to run a playbook with user account

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ansible

Is it anyhow possible to run an ansible task from `google.cloud` plugin using a user account (not a service account)? We have already set up a comprehensive hierarchy of user groups and roles and translating that into service account will be a pain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. Ansible google.cloud credentials must be service accounts.

Refer to the [Ansible GCE Guide](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_gce.html). `auth_kind` only changes how this service account is looked up:

- `serviceaccount`  Use the account from `service_account_file` or `service_account_contents`.  This one is possibly the easiest to use.
- `machineaccount` Use the service account associated with the GCP instance running Ansible.
- `application` Use [application default credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically) associated with the APIs provided by the `scopes` parameter.

---

Automation accounts should not be end user accounts. Removes the temptation to do something interactively as the automation user. API key style creds are strong, unlike garbage human passwords.

Creating an service account is easy. The hard part was validating the roles...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add SSH users, not exactly you Goole user, but you can create additional SSH keys to use with your ansible scripts.

Basically, you can add SSH keys to your VM instances in three ways:

1. Via CLI (GCloud SDK) on instance creation, passing parameter --metadata-from-file

   gcloud compute instance create my-instance --image-family=debian-10 --metadata-from-file ssh-keys=my-ssh-keys.pub

**Note** that your ssh-keys file must be [formated](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#sshkeyformat) as expected by Google:

2. Adding SSH users to specific VM instances

   On Cloud Console, go to **VM Instances** page, **Edit** it, and, under **SSH Keys**, click **Show and Edit**, add your SSH keys (**Add item**), and save it.

   [Adding or removing instance-level public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#instance-only)
3. Adding SSH users project-wide

   On Cloud Console, go to **metadata page** for your project, under **SSH Keys**, click **Edit**, and click **Add Item** to add your SSH key users

   [Adding or removing project-wide public SSH keys](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#project-wide)